# Cannot access attributes from associated model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have three models, ingredient, recipe_ingredient and recipy

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
end

class RecipeIngredient < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :recipy, :dependent => :destroy
 belongs_to :ingredient
end

class Recipy < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipy_steps
 has_many :recipe_ingredients, :dependent => :delete_all
end
```

I am trying to access the ing_name attribute in the ingredients table from recipies show page.

```
<% @recipe_ingredients.each do |ing| %>
<p> <%= ing.amount  %> <%= ing.unit %>
<%= ing.ingredient.ing_name %>
</p>
```

def Show from the recipies controller:

```
def show
 @recipe_ingredients = @recipy.recipe_ingredients
end
```

But I keep receiving the following error msg: 
undefined method `ing_name' for nil:NilClass

My ingredient_params:

```
def ingredient_params
params.require(:ingredient).permit(:ing_name)
end
```

It does seem to work like this:

```
    <%= Ingredient.where(id: ing.ingredient_id).pluck(:ing_name) %>
```

But this does not use the connection between the tables if I understand correctly? Any help? Thanks.

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: . undefined method `ing_name' for nil:NilClass but already solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have ingredient `nil` thats why you got the error.

Must be your controller has some before_action hook to load recipy

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_recipy, only: :show

  def show
    @recipe_ingredients = @recipy.recipe_ingredients
  end

 private
 def load_recipy
   @recipy = Recipy.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

You can [`try`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) this to avoid this nil error(`undefined method 'ing_name' for nil:NilClass`)

```
<% @recipe_ingredients.each do |ing| %>
<p> <%= ing.amount  %> <%= ing.unit %>
<%= ing.try(:ingredient).try(:ing_name) %>
</p>
```

From Rails 5 by default you got one `required` option to make ingredient always not `nullable`

like below

```
belongs_to :ingredient, required: true
```

It will also prevent this error of

```
class RecipeIngredient < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :recipy, :dependent => :destroy
 belongs_to :ingredient, required: true
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great now! I actually tried if it works only with one try as below: 
<%= ing.ingredient.try(:ing_name) %>
it seems ok. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is because inside your show method @recipy is nil, 
here is usually code for show

controller

```
def show
  @recipy = Recipy.find(params[:id]) # --> you missed this line
  @recipe_ingredients = @recipy.recipe_ingredients # @recipy will be null without line above
end
```

view

```
<% @recipe_ingredients.each do |ing| %>
  <p> <%= ing.amount  %> <%= ing.unit %> <%= ing.ingredient.ing_name %> </p>
<% end %>
```

I would like also add some suggestion to your model relationship as follow since Ingredient and Recipy shows many to many relationship

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  # -> recipe_ingredients -> recipies
  has_many :recipe_ingredients, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :recipies, through: :recipe_ingredients
end

class RecipeIngredient < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :recipy
 belongs_to :ingredient
end

class Recipy < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recipy_steps
  # -> recipe_ingredients -> ingredients
  has_many :recipe_ingredients, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients
end
```